# Is the "Compose" music tablet by Ouyang Xi available?

Tags: composition

Anyone know if this hardware device, where you write music on a tablet and it plays back, ever made it to market? (See link below). I would pay handsomely to get one. No jokes about using an iPad please! This device doesn't require software or the Internet.

https://www.musicradar.com/news/tech/compose-tablet-records-and-transcribes-your-songs-170099

Comment: There is [StaffPad](https://www.staffpad.net/) available for iPad

Comment: Such a one-trick pony might have made it to market a couple of years before the iPad was released…though by today's standards it would be dog-slow. it wouldn't have a chance in today's market.